# Reading a binary number

Tags: c++, binary

I'm working on a function to parse a binary number from a `std::string` into an `int`. Somehow, it fails.

```
int bin2dec(string &binstr)
 {
  unsigned int count = 0;
  int dec = 0;

  while (count < binstr.size()) {
    if(binstr[count] == '1') {
        dec += (dec + pow(2, count));
    } 
    count++;
   }
  return dec;
 }
```

Comment: You seem to be treating the leftmost bits as least significant and the rightmost bits as most significant, which is backwards compared to the more usual convention of having the LS bit on the right.

Comment: Since when is an `int` *decimal*? Also, using `pow` (and thus floating-point) here is a really bad idea.

Comment: I thought that as well, and tried reversing the string which I struggled with and then it did not fix it. When I enter 0001, the output is 8, thus you are right, but then if I enter 1111, i get 32, so I know I am doing something else wrong as well.

Comment: @budroothedog You could't find any help? Not even on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729347/binary-to-decimal)?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441364/how-to-read-a-binary-number-as-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be working left to right when you should be working in the opposite direction. You also have a bug in the line `dec += (dec + pow(2, count));`, since you're adding `dec` twice here. One possible way to fix your code:

```
int bin2dec(string &binstr)
{
    int count = 0;
    int dec = 0;

    while (count < binstr.size())
    {
        if (binstr[binstr.size() - index - 1] == '1')
        {
            dec += pow(2, count); // <<< bug fix here
        }
        count++;
    }
    return dec;
}
```

Note that using the floating point `pow()` library function is overkill - you can just use bitwise operators, e.g. change:

```
            dec += pow(2, count);
```

to:

```
            dec += (1 << count);
```

This avoids unnecessary int-float conversions and a math library call.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Removing the extra + dec fixed me.

Answer (score 3):

A relatively simple method to convert a string of binary digits to an integer is this:

```
int result = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < binstr.length(); index++)
{
    result *= 2;
    result += (binstr[index] - '0');
}
```

This method can be used for any base, replacing the `2` with `base`, up to 10 - beyond that you need to convert whatever other character is used to the relevant "digit-value" before adding it to result.

(Note that the above is significantly more efficient than using `pow`, as well as not having the potential for rounding errors that `pow` gives, since `pow` often is implemented as `exp(log(base) * n);`, which tends to come up with answers such as `7.999999` instead of 8 and `16.000001` insteaad of 16, leading to "interesting" results when it's converted to an integer)

[Obviously a proper conversion would need to check for overflow (too many digits) and that digits are "valid" for the base chosen]

Comment: I can't believe yours is the only solution which does _not_ use the `pow()` function.

Comment: @user5402: Added comment to clarify the REASON for not using `pow`.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating the binary string backwards - the first digit is given the value of 1 (2<sup>0</sup>), the second of 2 (2<sup>1</sup>), etc.

If you want to take this approach, you should iterate the string **backwards**:

```
int dec = 0;
for (int i = binstr.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  if(binstr[count] == '1') {
      dec += pow (2, i);
  } 
  count++;
}
```

Note:
As PaulR pointed out in the comments, you're adding `dec` to itself twice. You should either use `dec = dec + ...` or `dec += ...`, not a combination of the two.

Comment: @PaulR arg, right. Over-zealous copy-paste from the OP's code. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the comments above, you may want the assignment to be

```
dec += pow(2, count);
```

instead, or possibly

```
dec = (dec + pow(2, count));
```

Good luck!